# Meteor Testing Using Spies

Tags: meteor, tdd, bdd, chai

I'm using Velocity with the mike:mocha framework and the chai assertions. Everything is working great, but when it comes time to do stubbing, mocking and spying, I've hit a bit of a roadblock. These aren't core features of mike:mocha or chai, so I found [practicalmeteor:chai](https://github.com/practicalmeteor/meteor-sinon), which should/may have added spies.

My first stab at finding out whether this is true was to write the following code:

```
  it 'calls update when both documents are present but different', ->
    spies.create('log', console, 'log')
```

which gives me:

```
ReferenceError: spies is not defined
    at packages/velocity:test-proxy/tests/mocha/server/charger_server_doc_spec.coffee:88:9
    at wrappedFunc (packages/mike:mocha/server.js:200:1)
    at runWithEnvironment (packages/mike:mocha/server.js:156:1)
```

That implies to me that I've misunderstood what practicalmeteor:chai provides, however, the code I showed in the first example is copied verbatim from the README.

Question: Any tips on getting this to work? Is it a load order issue? The code on Github shows spies and so on are implemented in this package. So I'm a bit stuck.

Thanks!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The package `practicalmeteor:chai` does not include the `practicalmeteor:sinon` package which is required to get the `spies` API included.

They are separate packages because you may not have to use spies when creating basic tests with chai.

If you look at the [package.js](https://github.com/practicalmeteor/meteor-chai/blob/master/package.js) file in the `practicalmeteor:chai` package, it does not include the sinon files.

So, just running `meteor add practicalmeteor:sinon` should solve your problem.

Comment: Thanks! Still wrestling the syntax. I'm going with `expect(update_spy.called).to.equal(false)` for the time being, which seems like syntactic vinegar when compared with something like `expect(update_spy).to.be.called()`. Sadly, that syntax does not seem to be implemented. I may have to look at it :)